# Formal replacement for the phrase "ties back to"?

Tags: phrase-requests

The phrase "ties back to" is used frequently, but it feels awkward in a formal paper. I'm seeking a word or phrase which means the same thing, but has a more appropriate sound.

An example sentence is:

> This fact **ties back to** my initial interest in the subject.

Comment: Your need is a bit unclear.  Do you simply mean "references"?  Or perhaps "is related to" or "is derived from"?

Comment: What @HotLicks said. And *echoes*, *is related to*, or *refers to*.

Answer (score 3):

"Ties back to", as well as being informal, is also a vague phrase, meaning only that there is some kind of connection between the two things. With more formality you are probably going to want more precision, especially in a scientific paper.

Some suggestions might be:

- is caused by
- is due to
- is linked to
- refers back to
- connects back to